# Add a 1D numpy array to a 2D array along a new dimension (dimensions do not match)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to add a 1D array to a 2D array along the second dimension of the 2D array using the logic as in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
TwoDArray = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10000, 50))
OneDArray = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2000))
Sum = np.array([(TwoDArray+element).sum(axis=1) for element in OneDArray]).T
print(Sum.shape)
>> (10000, 2000)
```

This list comprehension is dramatically slow.
What is the fastest way to do this?
(I guess with array computation).

**EDIT**
I tried the following approach, but the running time was worst

```
Sum = np.sum(TwoDArray[:, np.newaxis, :] + OneDArray[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis], axis=2)
```

I also tried with Numba, but running time is the same.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def compute_sum(TwoDArray, OneDArray):
    return [(TwoDArray+element).sum(axis=1) for element in OneDArray]
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? The code looks like a bunch of operations mashed together for no clear purpose. You add each element of some list of random numbers to each element of a large array, and then sum the rows of the array, and collect each of the resulting 1d arrays in a new 2d array. There's many ways to optimise this, but what is the point of the code?

Comment: `(TwoDArray[:,:,None]+OneDArray[None,None,:]).sum(axis=1)` makes (10000,50,2000) shape array, followed by reduction to (10000,2000).  But then why not `TwoDArray.sum(axis=1)[:,None]*OneDArray`?

Comment: @Grismar, I promise that this is the exact case I am dealing with, and it makes sense business-wise for me. Sorry, I can't provide more explanations.

Comment: @hpaulj, your solution doesn't work (it doesn't replicate Sum)

Comment: The `broadcasted` version makes `(10000, 50, 2000)` temporary array, which starts hitting memory management issues, making it slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a performant Numba implementation, you have to write simple loops or in some cases use BLAS functions where applicable.

**Example 1**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def cust_sum(TwoDArray,OneDArray):
    #allocate Output
    res=np.empty((TwoDArray.shape[0],OneDArray.shape[0]),dtype=TwoDArray.dtype)

    for i in nb.prange(TwoDArray.shape[0]):
        for j in range(OneDArray.shape[0]):
            acc=0
            for k in range(TwoDArray.shape[1]):
                acc+=TwoDArray[i,k]+OneDArray[j]
            res[i,j]=acc
    return res

%timeit sum_2=cust_sum(TwoDArray,OneDArray)
#12.8 ms ± 498 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Edit: Example 2**

With some ideas from Nathan Furnals answer this can be modified to

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True,cache=True)
def cust_sum_2(TwoDArray,OneDArray):
    #allocate Output
    res=np.empty((TwoDArray.shape[0],OneDArray.shape[0]),dtype=TwoDArray.dtype)

    for i in nb.prange(TwoDArray.shape[0]):
        acc=0
        for k in range(TwoDArray.shape[1]):
            acc+=TwoDArray[i,k]
        for j in range(OneDArray.shape[0]):
            res[i,j]=acc+OneDArray[j]*TwoDArray.shape[1]
    return res

%timeit sum_2=cust_sum_2(TwoDArray,OneDArray)
#7.25 ms ± 815 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

print(np.allclose(cust_sum_2(TwoDArray,OneDArray),Sum))
#True
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we're adding the same value (each element of the 1D array) to the 2D array, it's equivalent to taking the sum of each axis and adding the 1D array **times** the dimension of the second axis of the 2D array. We must also add a new axis to the 1D array otherwise the shapes do  not match.

```py
import numpy as np

arr2d = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10000, 50))
arr1d = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=2000)
arr_sum = np.array([(arr2d+element).sum(axis=1) for element in arr1d]).T

out = (arr2d.sum(axis=1) + (arr1d * arr2d.shape[1])[:, np.newaxis]).T

print(out.shape == arr_sum.shape) # True
print(np.allclose(out, arr_sum))  # True
```

and

```py
In [22]: %timeit np.array([(arr2d+element).sum(axis=1) for element in arr1d]).T
1.86 s ± 20.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [23]: %timeit (arr2d.sum(axis=1) + (arr1d * arr2d.shape[1])[:, np.newaxis]).T
25.8 ms ± 226 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score -1):

Change - Sum = np.array([(TwoDArray+element).sum(axis=1) for element in OneDArray]).T

```
import numpy as np

TwoDArray = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10000, 50))
OneDArray = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(2000))

Sum = TwoDArray.dot(np.ones((50, 2000))) + OneDArray

print(Sum.shape)
```

Comment: Thank you for this fast implementation, but your Sum doesn't match my Sum.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).